# Expected Condition WebDriverWait Python Selenium Question

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am populating a list of elements and then I am iterating through each element in the list. How do I implement a wait condition to tell the code to wait 15 seconds before failing to find the element? Specifically I want **currentprice** and **title** to try and wait until element is visible rather than just hard execute when it hits that line of code.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.list-wrap div.item-container')
print(len(elements))

for x in range(len(elements)):
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.list-wrap div.item-container')))
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.list-wrap div.item-container')
    currentprice = elements[x].find_element_by_css_selector('li.price-current').text
    title = elements[x].find_element_by_css_selector('a.item-title').text
...
```

I tried the following but I am getting the error that WebDriverWait is not a method of elements.

```
elements[x].WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.price-current')))
```

Comment: See here what the documentation says: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.
The `WebDriverWait` expect a driver instance as first parameter. The `WebElement` object has the driver object in its instance and also implement most of the WebDriver methods.

Having that in mind, you can create a new `WebDriverWait` and pass your element instead of the driver.

Instead of:

```
elements[x].WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.price-current')))
```

Use:

```
WebDriverWait(elements[x], 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.price-current')))
```